# SQL Server query with multiple filters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I am writing a query on 3 tables "table1", "table2", "tableMap". based on selected values from dropdown. But I am not getting the expected result. Please help.

Dropdown 1:

```
<Promo Name>
- All - value = ""
- ABC - value = "1"
- XYZ - value = "2"
```

Dropdown 2:

```
<Store Type>
- All - value = ""
- Type 1 - value = "1"
- Type 2 - value = "2"
```

Dropdown 3:

```
<Store Area>
- All - value = ""
- Area 1 - value = "1"
- Area 2 - value = "2"
```

Table 1:

```
ID | Store Name | Store Address | Store Type | Store Area
---+------------+---------------+------------+-----------
1  | ABC        |  112 test road| Type 1     | Area 1
2  | XYZ        |  22 test2 road| Type 2     | Area 2
```

Table 2:

```
ID | Promo Name  
---+------------
1  | promo 1    
2  | promo 2
```

Table map:

```
ID | Promo ID   | Store Type | Store Area
---+------------+----------------+------------+-----------
1  | 1          | 2,1        |
2  | 2          |            | 1
```

The values for [Store Type] and [Store Area] are the IDs of [Table 1]
So in the query below, we should map the [Store Type] / [Store Area] with the [ID] of [Table 1]

I am trying to write a query so I can get result based on dropdown selected values.

Query:

```
declare @promoname varchar(255),
        @type varchar(255),
        @area varchar(255)

select  
    t2.Promo Name, t2.ID, t1.Store Name, t1.Store Address
from 
    [Tablemap] tm  
inner join 
    [Table2] t2 on tm.Promo ID = t2.ID
where 
    (@promoname = '' or t2.[promoname] = @promoname)
    and (@type = '' or @type in (select [name] 
                                 from dbo.SplitString (tm.Store Type)))
```

RESULT - expected - (but not working with above query as I didn't add location table above and not sure how to add it):

```
Promo Name | Store Name | Address
-----------+------------+---------------
promo 1    | ABC        | 112 test road
promo 2    | ABC        | 112 test road
```

Comment: Thank you for providing well formatted examples. I don't see table 2 in your query. I see t2 prefixed for values but I don't see it in the from or join clause.

Comment: What is the logic behind wanting `promo 2` to be associated with `ABC` in your desired results?

Comment: If you can you should modify the nature of 'table map' so that it does not contain a csv list of store type IDs.  Create a new row for each and every time a promo is associated with a particular area or store type.  This will make your life MUCH easier.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
declare @promoname varchar(255),
        @type varchar(255),
        @area varchar(255)

select  t2.Promo Name, t2.ID, t1.Store Name, t1.Store Address
from 
    [Tablemap] tm
inner join [Table2] t2 on tm.Promo ID = t2.ID
inner join [Table1] t1 on tm.Promo ID = t1.ID
where (@promoname = '' or t2.[promoname] = @promoname)
    and (@type = '' or t1.[Store Type] in (select [name] from dbo.SplitString (tm.Store Type)))
```